# git работа с репозиторием в расшаренной папке

Tags: git

Есть удаленный сервер, с расшаренной папкой по пути \server-ip\share.
В share через Git Bash Here выполняю git init - все ок, папка .git создается.
При выполнении git status наблюдаю следующую структуру папок:

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    ../../../../../../../../application/
    ../../../../../../../../css/
    ../../../../../../../../favicon.ico
    ../../../../../../../../ielte10.php
    ../../../../../../../../index.php
    ../../../../../../../../js/
```

...

И при попытке выполнить git add "path" получаю ошибку fatal: pathspec 'path' did not match any files.

Какой я path только ни ставил, всегда попадаю на эту ошибку.
Что я не так делаю? Что за гигантские пути вида "../../.. ..."?

PS: К консоли сервера доступа нет для установки git-а там.

Comment: Есть предположение, что на 8 уровней выше в папке есть также каталог .git. Вот оно его и нашло

Comment: Возможно, у вас второй сервер linux-машина и есть какие-то особенности? Не знаю, подобного опыта никогда не было, т.к. на linux серверах у меня есть возможность ставить git и я работаю с ним локально. А вот на windows машине прекрасно работает с шарами с других win-серверов (подключенных как локальный диск). Так же из VmWare постоянно работаю - и то же без проблем. Так что я и не думал, что в таком простом сценарии могут быть сбои.

Comment: @A K Верно, сейчас попробовал создать репоз-ий на заведомо известных Win и linux расшаренных папках. В Win без проблем, а в Linux наблюдаю подобные гигантские пути.

Comment: А зачем создавать репозиторий в расшаренной папке?

Comment: @A K Разобрался, подключил папку как сетевой диск выполнил git status и увидел нормальные пути. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @KoVadim Дабы была возможность работать из любого места локальной сети и при этом иметь контроль над происходящим.

Comment: как то мне кажется, что это неверное использование системы контроля версий. Если с двух машин одновременно пойти комититься... Правильно - поднять сервер git и каждый у себя держит отдельно репу.

Comment: @KoVadim Возможно вы и правы, возможно и сервер будет, но git освоить нужно сейчас. Принцип то такой же - в папке репозиторий, с локальных ПК сети клоним/пушим/учимся)